# Using a dynamic variable name, as an argument for a function/method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using a dynamic variable name, as an argument for a function/method:

I need something like:

```
PObjectName.update(f'add_{attr_name}_tek'=data)
```

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to dynamically build a set of named arguments for a function call, you can use a dictionary and pass it using the `**` operator to expand it in the function call.

concretely, you can do this way:

```
kwargs = {f'add_{attr_name}_tek': data}

PObjectName.update(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with unpacking a dict of keyword arguments:

```
def foo(add_attr_name_tek):
    print(add_attr_name_tek)

attr_name = 'attr_name'

foo(**{f'add_{attr_name}_tek': 'value'})
```